# Zero-initialized struct not appear in memory

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, ld, osdev

I am learning assembly and it amazed me that, a zero-initialized struct does not occupy in the memory.
My code is like that.

```
// in file a.cpp
#include <stdint.h>
struct Bar {
    char filename[8];
    // ignore members here
    uint32_t filesize;
}__attribute__((packed));

typedef struct FAT_ITEM FAT_ITEM;

Bar bar1 = {
    "null",0
};
Bar bar2 = {
    "",0
};
```

then I compile the codes

```
gcc -march=i386 -m16 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -ffreestanding -O0 a.cpp a.o
ld -melf_i386 -N --oformat binary -o a.bin a.o
```

However, when I use `dd` to read the binary in a.bin, I see

```
00000000: 6e75 6c6c 0000 0000 0000 0000            null........
(END)
```

`bar2` does not appear in the memory.
the 32-bits zero comes from `bar1.filesize`. And `(END)` follows.

I am learning 16bits x86 assembly, so the compile options may be strange. But I think they won't cause this problem.

Can anyone help me and explain why `bar2` is "ignored"?

Comment: it's not being ignored per-se, try using `readelf` or `elfdump` - compiler is more than likely reserving the space but since it's zeroed, not storing it on disk

can't confirm my assumptions on this machine, but there are similar conventions in most executable formats

Comment: The default linker script used to link will place the zero initialised data in the BSS section. The BSS section of the default linker script will place it in memory after what is physically written into the file. If you are writing your own OS (or bootloader) and loading a.bin into memory yourself, it is up to you to initialize the BSS section to zero.

Comment: Note: you flagged the question as C, but you are compiling it as C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler that places zero-inited stuff in the BSS, [which the default linker script doesn't allocate space for in a flat binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504049/zero-initialized-struct-not-appear-in-memory#comment86012424_49504049); it starts after the end of the other sections.

Zero it yourself on startup before your C code runs, or disable the compiler's use of the BSS (e.g. [`-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

You can look at `gcc -S` output; note the [`.lcomm` or `.comm` directives](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html#Lcomm) which reserve BSS space for all zero-init static / global variables.  When compiling a normal Linux executable, you don't want huge arrays of zeros explicitly stored in the executable.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-07/msg00097.html for some discussion, e.g. you could use an `__attribute__` to put an array that actually needs to be zero-inited into a different section, if you don't want to write a zero-init loop that runs on startup.  Then you can have some arrays that don't need to be initialized at all still in the BSS, but spend space in your binary for explicit zeros on other things that need it.